# how can prevent remaining table rows from ng-repeat start in nested json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
property  in homepalGroupProp.properties
```

my json data :

```
property=[{unitname : 1bhk, data:[{}]] }, {unit name : 3bhk},{}]
```

like this

```
{
    "UnitName": "3 BHK",
    "data": [
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1521 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6538779,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 51,
        "$$hashKey": "object:65"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1523 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6547377,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 52,
        "$$hashKey": "object:66"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1525 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6555975,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 53,
        "$$hashKey": "object:67"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1526 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6560274,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 54,
        "$$hashKey": "object:68"
    }
    ],
        "$$hashKey": "object:46"
}
```

my html code :

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="property in homepalGroupProp.properties" ng-show="project.properties.length>3" ng-click="homepalGroupProp.expanded = !homepalGroupProp.expanded">
    <td ng-click="projectListingCluster(property.data,homepalGroupProp.expanded)">{{property.UnitName}}
        <span ng-if="!homepalGroupProp.expanded">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span></td>
    <td><span>{{}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{property.price_per_sqft}}</span></td>
</tr>



<tr ng-if="homepalGroupProp.expanded" ng-repeat="prop in currentdata" ng-repeat-end="">

    <td>{{prop.UnitName}}</td>
    <td>{{prop.UnitPrice}}</td>
    <td>{{}}</td>
</tr>
```

controller code :

```
 $scope.projectListingCluster=function (p,ex,$index) {
     alert(ex +"..ex");
     alert(p+"..p");
     $scope.currentdata=p;
     alert(JSON.stringify($scope.currentdata));
     alert($index);
 }
```

i am getting loop is perfect but when i am clicking on first row like 1bhk.its opening all the rows.so i want to hide the two rows(2bhk,3bhk).if i clicked on two rows then its can show two rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quit using alerts for your debugging and start using console.log

Comment: ya.iam using that only.please try to give the solution